# How to create external js file for a popup procedure that can be used in any page?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a popup box that shows information about my site. I make this popup dynamically. I retrieve information from database and show in that popup box. I want to show this popup box to the lower-right corner of every page in my website.

Here is my info_popup.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var quest = $('input[name=info]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'info_popup.js',
            data:{quest:quest},
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
          });
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        include("../config.php");

        $sql = "select info from my_info";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $info = $row['info'];

            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$info\" id=\"info\" name=\"info\" >";

        }

        echo "<div id=\"dialog\" title=\"Information\" >";
        echo $info."<br/>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In my info_popup.js

```
var info = $('input[name=info]').val();
    alert(info);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen:true,
            width:'auto',
            modal: true,
        }); 
        $(window).resize(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
        });
```

I think I need to change in this js file. But I don't know how.

When I run info_popup.php, I can see popup box with information.

The main point I want to make is, when I call this js from my home page or any other page like this

```
<script src="www.myurl.com/js/info_popup.js">
```

I want to show the whole procedure of information with popup box. Because I don't want to write the whole procedure of popup box in every page.

After I add this script to my home.php and run, its not work.

I don't know, how to make it because I am newbie in web development. I very appreciate for any advice.

Comment: show us the code you alredy got

Comment: The function that will call the pop call it in the begin of this file or you can call it direct (function test() { ... });

Comment: Minzkraut, now I show my code and help me to solve the problem in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check if header or footer is common in your site.

If yes then put below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="full path to file"></script>
```

If not then you need to put same code on all files where needed.

please let me know if more help is required.

Comment: I make changes in my post. please check again

Comment: you need to include  info_popup.php in all files else in one common file. please make sure any js css is not include twice on the page. For including file use php function require_once() function

Comment: But I don't want to use include(). I want to call .js file. Please give me idea of external js to make this.

Comment: Just put below code inside the head tags:- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myurl.com/js/info_popup.js"></script>

Comment: If any issue check mozilla console, This will help you.

Comment: When I call script as you said in my home.php, I get only undefined alert and its nothing show in console.

Comment: Did you provide value in the info input box?

Comment: press ctrl+u, check source for input box is exist or not

Comment: you can also replace $('input[name=info]').val() with $('#info').val()

Comment: I mean when I call js form my home.php and run that home.php, I can only get undefined alert. I don't run from info_popup.php.

Comment: your code is in info_popup.php, and this will not exist on the home.php so please remember all html and js should be present on home.php

Comment: Is there any other way to call whole procedure of popup by js?

Comment: Create a new file put here js and html/php code and include this file where is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just before your `</head>` tag in every page, put your code, and just to be extra sure put the code mentioned by Deepak Dholiyan, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.myurl.com/js/login_popup.js"></script>
```

For Testing, if you download the js script to your computer and added the file path in the **src** from your desktop it might help.